# How to symlink in saltstack latest version or file

Tags: salt-stack

```sh
ln -fs /opt/app/$(ls -rt file-*.jar | tail -n1) /opt/app/file.jar
```

works in bash very well

dir contains

```
file-1.jar
file-2.jar
file-3.jar
```

How can I do this in a salt stack state sls formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this in Saltstack we need roughly two steps:

1. Get the latest file
2. Link the file

For the first part, we can use some salt module such as [file.find](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.find), but I feel the existing logic of using `ls -rt` is simpler.

So we can use this command to get the latest JAR file into a variable. Then use a Salt state to link the file.

Example:

```yaml
{% set latest_jar = salt.cmd.run('ls -rt /opt/app/file-*.jar | tail -n1') %}

link-latest-jar:
  file.symlink:
    - name: /opt/app/file.jar
    - target: {{ latest_jar }}
```

*Update:*

With newer version of Saltstack we need to use `salt.cmd.shell` to set the `latest_jar` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set latest_jar = salt['cmd.shell']('ls -rt /opt/app/file-*.jar | tail -n1') %}

link-latest-jar:
  file.symlink:
    - name: /opt/app/file.jar
    - target: {{ latest_jar }}
```

works for me... thx for help

Comment: Perfect, I realized that with newer versions of Saltstack we need to use `cmd.shell`, should I update my answer?

Comment: i think it´s okay. Thank you for you help.

Comment: This is an exact copy of the other answer, but without explanation